# No me lee de un runat server en mi web en .net

Tags: html, c#, jquery, .net, aspx

estoy empezando con .net, y quiero leer en mi .cs el texto de un input de mi html, pero me sale siempre vacío, en mi html genero con jquery el valor del texto, es decir, no viene dado por defecto pero en el .cs me sale que está en blanco, este es el código de mi .aspx (frontend):

```
 <input type='text' id='tiempoMilisegundos' runat='server' class = "tiempoMilisegundos" />
                   
 <script>            
    let tmpDate = new Date();
    let now = tmpDate.getTime();
    $('.tiempoMilisegundos').val(now);
 </script>
```

y en mi código del .aspx.cs (backend) tengo lo siguiente para leer del input

```
string milisegundos = tiempoMilisegundos.Value;
Page.Response.Write("<script>console.log('tiempo 1 -> " + milisegundos + "');</script>");
```

pero siempre me sale vacío, aunque en el input si que se ven los datos, ¿como puedo solucionar esto?? Muchas gracias.

Comment: con código .aspx.cs estas refiriéndote al servidor? ten en cuenta que estas intentando realizar dos cosas diferentes, con jquery lo estas ejecutando desde el lado cliente y desde asp el servidor, si es desde el servidor puede estar fallándote por que no lo estas enviando antes de cargar la página

Comment: Buenas, desde el servidor tengo el aspx.cs y en mi frontend tengo el jquery, pero si cargo el trozo de codigo que lee ene l backend despues de cargar la pagina, me falla diciendo que no existe en ese contexto y demás

Comment: Es que lo que intento hacer es pasar la hora actual a milisegundos en el js y mandarlo al .cs, ya que no logro hacerlo desde el .cs, entonces una vez cargada la página le añado la hora al input y se lo paso al servidor pero no funciona.

Comment: para pasar el parametro desde el cliente al servidor tienes que realizar una peticion, es decir, si lo que deseas es enviar el parametro generado en el cliente desde jquery, puedes realizar un [metodo ajax](https://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/4/10/formularios-web-ajax-con-jquery-en-aspnet-core-mvc)

Comment: Pero siendo esto .net, como puedo hacer el ajax es decir, en el servidor como puedo recoger los datos que le paso en esa llamada?? muchas gracias

Comment: creo que [este ejemplo](http://respag.net/hola-mundo-con-aspnet-ajax.aspx) te puede ser de ayuda, siento de no disponer de tiempo para escribirte una respuesta en condiciones

Comment: Sin problemas, muchas gracias por la ayuda.